# X3D Export - adding a title

Tags: export

Is there a way to add a title to an X3D (3D) plot that is exported using `Export[]`?
I didn't have much success with exporting a `Text[]` into an X3D file.
I also know that X3D files have several properties (meta tags) that could be helpful, but I don't know how to specify them in the `Export[]` command.

```
plot = Plot3D[x^2 + y^2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotLabel -> "MyPlot"];
scaledPlot = plot /. Graphics3D[gr_, opts___] -> 
   Graphics3D[GeometricTransformation[gr, ScalingTransform[{1, 1, 0.5}]], opts];
Export["plot.x3d", Show[scaledPlot, Graphics3D[Text["MyPlot"]]]]
```

Answer (score 5):

I think the answer is: No, it cannot be done using `Export` alone. According to the documentation, there is no meta data listed in the [elements available](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/X3D.html#26021) for export, nor in the [options](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/X3D.html#23811).

To accomplish what you would like to do, however, can be done via a two step process. First, save your plot as an X3D file, and the `Import` it as an XML file, as follows

```
Export["plot.x3d"]
plotxml = Import["plot.x3d", "XML"]
```

Then, it is just a matter of inserting your element into the [XML tree](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/XMLImportAndExport.html). From a brief browsing of the [X3D spec](http://www.web3d.org/x3d/specifications/schema/), I am not sure of the specific element you need to insert you data into. Likely, though, your new element will be a `MetadataString`, so it should look like

```
mdat = XMLElement["MetadataString", {"name" -> "Title", "value" -> "MyPlot", ...}, {}]
```

And, once you have found which element it belongs in, you can use

```
plotxml = plotxml /. XMLElement["ParentElement", attrs_, data_]:>
   XMLElement["ParentElement", attrs_, Append[data, mdat];
```

It is likely that you will have to specify the `attrs` list to only affect the specific element you are looking for.